# Uniform position principle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The uniform position theorem says that the points of a general hyperplane section of an irreducible curve lie in uniform position. Doesn't that imply that the points of a general subspace of codimension $k$ of an irreducible variety of dimension $k$ lie in uniform position?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. I assume that by a "general codimension $k$ linear subspace" you would mean something like the intersection of $k$ general hyperplanes.

A general codimension $k-1$ linear subspace intersects an irreducible variety (I assume you include "reduced" in "variety") in an irreducible and reduced curve. Then the intersection of the original variety with a general codimension $k$ linear subspace is the same as the intersection of this curve with a general hyperplane, hence your desired statement follows from the original theorem you are mentioning.

Comment: You need to be sure that the curve is nondegenerate. This follows from e.g. Harris Algebraic Geometry Proposition 18.10.