# Linearly dependent points and the uniform position theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

One proof of the uniform position theorem (as stated in p. 109 or p. 113 in Section III.1 of "Geometry of Algebraic Curves") uses a monodromy argument. While this gives us something even more general than the usual statement of the uniform position theorem, it isn't something that is constructive.

What is currently known about the locus of hyperplanes whose intersection with a curve gives a linearly dependent collection of points? Is there an analogue involving higher dimensional varieties? The reason I'm not sure is that uniform position in higher dimensional varieties involves intersection with generic hyperplanes ([Uniform position principle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253941/uniform-position-principle)). As a start, there is generalization of the usual statement of the uniform position theorem involving divisors containing a given hyperplane section (p. 113 in ACGH above). However, it has been difficult to find concrete examples where this non-generic situation is considered.